# Add shortcut keys to Ckeditor?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I need to add some shortcuts to Ckeditor to use on Macintosh

In **Custom JavaScript configuration** I added this code, but is not working at all.

```
    config.keystrokes = [

[ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 49 /*1*/, 'heading-h1' ],
[ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 50 /*2*/, 'heading-h2' ],
[ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 51 /*3*/, 'heading-h3' ],
[ CKEDITOR.CTRL + 52 /*4*/, 'heading-h4' ]

];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this; place wherever you replace the ckeditor. I do it differently in my app and I can't see where or how you replace/extend/customize the editor so I can't give you better instructions without seeing more of your app :)

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    var editor = ev.editor;
    editor.addCommand('heading-h1', {
        modes: { wysiwyg: 1, source: 1 },
        exec: function (editor) {
            alert("NEIGH! I AM A PONY! ASDASDASD");
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I tried adding that to my custom ckeditor.config.js file. But I get an error saying: "editor is not defined"

Comment: Not to the config, but rather where you initialize the editor. The place to insert it depends on how you use and customize the editor. What code do you use to initialize ckeditor? For me the `editor` is an editor instance and I add the command in the same place I overwrite the save plugin. I'm guessing you don't do that so you just might have to experiment with different locations, such as `instanceReady`. I'll edit to add that test but no guarantees that it happens in the correct place then, testing is needed.

Comment: in my situation ckeditor functionality is provided via a module (Drupal). I'll try to find the code which initialize the editor.

Comment: Ah ok, I've never used Drupal - I thought you were just using the pure javascript version. Hopefully it will be easy to find! If you have any custom plugins you could try adding the command there too. I really don't know how to add it inside the config.